# onActivityResult() not called after startActivityForResult() with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I got my main `Activity` which holds different `Fragment`'s, one fragment gives the user a possibility to open a `DialogFragment`. That dialog opens a list of sound files and the dialog also contains a 'Add' button from which the user should be able to add her own soundfile. To do this I thought to use the standard Android file picking functionality and make use of the `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. So I fire away this intent when the user presses the 'Add' button and the Android file picking functionality comes up as it should, but when I choose a file, nothing happens what so ever. I would expect the `onActivityResult()`of my main activity to be triggered but it doesn't, and I can't get it to work and I don't understand why this doesn't work.

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Rest omitted...
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info) 
            .setTitle(R.string.TONE_PROMPT_TITLE)       

            .setNeutralButton(R.string.ADD, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_SOUND_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            })

            .create();
}
```

}

I have also tried to instantiate the intent the following way:
`Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);`
but this doesn't work either.

Any ideas would be really helpful, thanks!

Comment: Where have you the code for `onActivityResult()`? In activity or fragment? When using multiple fragments in an activity implementation changes a little.

Comment: Which activity processes the request? Other app or some of yours?

Comment: It's an activity within the same application, more exactly the activity in which all the fragments belong to.

Comment: Could it maybe be some intentfilter that's missing in the manifest for my activity? Has understood it's not needed to have any when you are receiving data this way, but when passing data from my application then it needed? Or is this incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to figure out what the problem was... 
In my manifest I have declared my `Activity` as `android:noHistory="false"` and this was the problem. After setting it to `android:noHistory="true"` for my activity and firing my `Intent`the following way it worked like a charm.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("audio/mpeg");           
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_SOUND_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And just like that, the `onActivityResult()` in my activity was triggered just as it should and after that I followed @Rohit5k2's advice on how to get my `Fragment`'s OnActivityResult() triggered and all has worked really great!

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    MyFragment fragmentObject = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    fragmentObject.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Do this in your activity which holds the fragments

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    MyFragment fragmentObject = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    fragmentObject.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

then `onActivityResult()` in your fragment will be called.

Comment: Doesn't work, I have debugged this and onActivityResult() placed in my activity doesn't get called, unfortunately

Comment: Then something else is wrong. It works for me. Only difference is that I am starting my own activity. Please put your relevant activity code

Comment: It's nothing to show really, a overridden `onActivityResult()` in my Activity with a Log line in it for debuggin purpose. Not really anything strange.

Answer (score 0):

In fragments you'd generally use `this.startActivityForResult(...)` and override the fragment's method `onActivityResult(...)`. Since your case is a `DialogFragment` this would be useless as the dialog would be destroyed after pressing one of its buttons.

That means you correctly called `getActivity().startActivityForResult(...)` but since the caller is the activity, the activity is the one that has to implement the `onActivityResult(...)` method. No fragments receive the callback when taking this approach.

Comment: I totally agree with you and understand this, but the problem is that onActivityResult() in my activity doesn't get called

Comment: @Robert: Oh yes I forgot to mention `ADD_SOUND_REQUEST_CODE` should be greater than 0. Thanks @Eugen for pointing that out.